# Unsigned packages on Emacs

Tags: emacs

I am using one of the most recent nightly builds for Emacs, and in the package manager, when I run `M-x list-packages` I see a column called `status` with an entry for each package. The values are:

- `available`
- `unsigned`
- `built-in`
- `obsolete`

One of the packages I care about is `AUCTeX`, but it says `unsigned` next to its version (`11.87.4`). What does `unsigned` mean here? Can I still install it/upgrade it, and if so, **how?**

See snapshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unsigned` denotes an **installed** package which has no signature or whose signature was not verified.

Emacs 24.4 introduces package signing.  Package authors can sign packages with GPG keys.  These signatures can then be verified with GPG upon installation, to ensure that the package has not been tampered with.  If a package signature was successfully verified, Emacs lists the package as “installed”, otherwise it lists the package as “unsigned”.

Currently, signatures are entirely optional, and verification is enforced by default.  The popular 3rd party archives Marmalade and MELPA do not support signatures.

The standard GNU archive does, and most of the contained packages are signed, but you need GPG installed to verify signatures.  Apparently you do not have GPG installed, and thus Emacs cannot verify the signature of AUCTeX.

Comment: Thanks, but I have `gpg` installed: `which gpg` returns `/usr/local/bin/gpg`. And `gpg --version` returns `gpg (GnuPG) version 1.4.16 ...`.

Comment: @user815423426 GPG in `/usr/local/`?  OS X?  Does Emacs find `gpg`?

Comment: Thanks. Yes it does. `shell-command (M-!) RET gpg --version` returns `gpg (GnuPG) version 1.4.16 ...`, and `M-! RET which gpg` returns the correct path as well.

Comment: @user815423426 And what about `M-: (executable-find "gpg")`?

Comment: Thanks. It also returns `"/usr/local/bin/gpg"`